# sql distinct and where condtion cant differentiate between uppercase and lowercase data

Tags: mysql, sql

Let suppose i have `Table A` which contain field name `brand` now this brand field has two rows of data

```
Column `brand`
row1-> "zazikhan's"
row2-> "ZAZIKHAN'S"
```

Now when i run select query normally it return both rows e.g.

```
SELECT 
    brand
FROM
    `TableA` 
    WHERE brand="ZAZIKHAN'S"
```

But what i was expecting only one record which is `row2->"ZAZIKHAN'S"` but it return me the both rows.

And same is the case with distinct and order by functions.
for e.g

```
SELECT 
        distinct(brand)
    FROM
        `TableA` 
        WHERE brand="ZAZIKHAN'S"
```

Now this query return me only one record which `row1->zazikhan's` which is weird i am expecting both rows in result cause both are change according to case

Comment: search something like case sensitive collation mysql

Comment: Distinct is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. (`select distinct (c1), c2...` eq `select distinct c1, c2...` eq `select distinct c1, (c2)...`...)

Comment: good but as for my know () these braces are called method or functions that why i mention distinct functions as the braces were there and if there is any other suitable word to distinct please let me know i will be using it in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting your field using [**a case sensitive collation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) like `latin1_general_cs`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(brand USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26665/6)

Comment: yes i change the whole database collation before your answer and it works but will mark you question as accepted cause its the right answer although thanks for your precious time